# Wen using react-navigation for modals, isFocused becomes useless

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I wanted to bring our app's modal system into react-navigation for various reasons, and did a little research and found their own implementations amongst others.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal

I have a very large app and it has taken a couple of days to move the system over. I now have a setup that looks something like this:

```
TopNavigator
    |
    --- MyAppNavigator
    |          |
    |          ---- SomeScreen
    |          ---- SomeScreen2
    |
    --- MyModal
```

The modal screen has a transparent background and is using 'modal' mode

Now this is finished I have suddenly realised that isFocus changes every time i open a modal (I know - obvious - i should have looked into this at the start). This is really bad as I am using this effect to load data, scroll to the beginning of lists and a bunch of other things which is all interrupted by the modal.

I have tried to make my own hook that changes isFocused only if the new route is not MyModal, but this doesn't seem possible as blur and focus events have no additional data, and state event is not fired when MyModal is added to the stack.

I've also read a ton of docs and looked through all the available hooks in the react-nav codebase but nothing seems to help.

This seems to entirely break the concept of using react-navigation for modals!!

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "5.8.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "5.12.3",
```

Comment: Hey, Is there no way you do not bring modals into navigation? I mean, what are some of the reasons you must do this?

Comment: In our situation our modals were becoming more and more complex, for instance there is a requirement to navigate from modal to modal and maintain it in history so to me i made sense to make them screens that just look like modals.
Also the standard react native implementation of modals is terrible as it occupies a totally separate native layer, leading to a bunch of touch event problems, mainly on Android
To answer to your question, yes I could implement this another way, but I didn't realise this was an issue until I had already spend 2 days refactoring it.

Comment: Understood. I don't understand why `state` event is not fired when your modal screen is added to the stack. Is this issue only with modal screen or with other screens as well? And can you also please share some code on how are you trying to handle `focus` and `state` events, so may be I can try to help.

Comment: About 'state' event. I believe it's not in the current stack navigator, but in the parent one (root). So you would probably need to check for parent navigator state to catch modal appear